# Laravel 6 Blade - Display all images inside a public folder?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I am having trouble figuring out a way to reach and display the contents of a folder located in 'public/images'. The goal is to have a blade file that acts as a gallery and displays all the images added to that specific folder.

I know how to access specific files using `asset('images/imagename.png')` but I need to get all of them at once.

Can I simply create a loop inside of the blade file or do I need to make a controller/route for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@foreach(File::glob(public_path('images').'/*') as $path)
   <img src="{{ str_replace(public_path(), '', $path) }}">
@endforeach
```

Comment: Okay so replacing 'js' with 'images', my folder name, it seems to correctly find the images and display them.

Answer (score 1):

You could do use `glob` method of the `File` facade if you know the directory. The following code assumes every file in the `public/images/` folder is an image.

```xml
<div class="container">
    @forelse (File::glob('public/images/*') as $file)
        <img src="{{ $file }}">
    @else
        <p id="no-images">No images in folder</p>
    @endforelse
</div>
```

Comment: Seems it can't read any images in there. I tried setting it to other folders as well without any luck. Calling them using asset() still works though.

Comment: Weird. Do you get an array of images if you try running `File::glob('public/images/*')` in the artisan console?

Comment: It seems it cannot find anything unless I do @forelse(File::glob(public_path('/images/*')) as $file). However, while it seems to fetch all images this instead gives me error that it's not allowed to load local resources.

Comment: If you use public_path, you'll get the local address instead of the uri.

Comment: Strange. I can't seem to get it to find the images otherwise, I've been trying different paths and everything but returns empty unless I do the public_patch function.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#directories) implies, you can get all files in a specific directory with:

```
Storage::files($directory);
```

So, you can iterate like this:

```
@foreach(Storage::files($directory) as $file)
    <img src="{{ $file }}">
@endforeach
```